# Android Studio 3 disable aapt2 causeed crash

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

as soon as I change `android.enableAapt2 = false` in `gradle.properties`, app crashes with below exception with Android Studio 3 C5, gradle plugin 3.0.0-alpha5

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the current theme features: { windowActionBar: false, windowActionBarOverlay: false, android:windowIsFloating: false, windowActionModeOverlay: false, windowNoTitle: false }
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:474)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:328)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:289)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
```

reenable it seems working fine